# Apostrophecms: Image Manager hanging on replicated site

Tags: linux, image, migration, apostrophe-cms

I've replicated an apostrophe site from a dev server to a production server. Both are linux servers. The steps performed are:

1. Push the entire project directory tree over to the new server (via git).
2. The git post-receive hook will call npm -install which will install everything specified in the package.json file
3. Migrate the DB using mongodump and mongo restore.

When the production site is started up (via node app.js) the blog text and images are present. There are no widgets created and thus not they're populated, however, this is no big deal as I can recreate and repopulate them.

The problem occurs when I go into the Images Manager dialog. If I do anything in the Image Manager i.e. to add an an image to a widget, the browser becomes unresponsive. BTW, all of the images from the original site are present in the Image Manager so the DB is in sync with the uploads/attachments dir. Here is the console output from the broswer:

```
jquery.js:1444 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at String.replace (<anonymous>)
at Function.Sizzle.matchesSelector (beap.ie/modules/apostrophe-assets/js/vendor/jquery.js:1444:14)
at Function.jQuery.filter (beap.ie/modules/apostrophe-assets/js/vendor/jquery.js:2709:15)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) [as parent] (beap.ie/modules/apostrophe-assets/js/vendor/jquery.js:3059:17)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (beap.ie/modules/apostrophe-images/js/manager-modal.js:30:17)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (http://beap.ie/modules/apostrophe-assets/js/vendor/jquery.js:4670:9)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (beap.ie/modules/apostrophe-assets/js/vendor/jquery.js:4338:28)
at Object.trigger (http://beap.ie/modules/apostrophe-assets/js/vendor/jquery.js:4579:12)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (hbeap.ie/modules/apostrophe-assets/js/vendor/jquery.js:5289:17)
at Function.each (beap.ie/modules/apostrophe-assets/js/vendor/jquery.js:384:23)
```

I checked the linux server with the top command and there's no unusual workload.
Here' my package.json file dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apostrophe": "^2.0.0",
    "apostrophe-blog": "^2.0.0",
    "html2plaintext": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^3.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.14.1"
  }
}
```

The code base on both servers is identical as they both originate from the same git repo and the same post-receive hook is run.

Have I missed a step in the migration?

Comment: There are no errors on the server? You don't have a front-end build tool or front-end package manager that also needs to run a build/install process? Have you tried deploying to the 2nd server via stagecoach or however you originally deployed to the first server?

Comment: Answers to Stuart's questions would be helpful - what we really need here is a way to reproduce the problem. It works in one environment and doesn't work in another. What is different? Also, what version of Apostrophe do you actually have? (Check package.json in node_modules/apostrophe on the server. Also consider running "npm update" to make sure it's the latest and restarting Apostrophe.)

Comment: @StuartRomanek  and boutell, Thanks for getting back quickly. I was looking for confirmation on the migration/deployment process - not to debug a server to which you have no visibility. Sorry for the confusion. I've just had a glance at Stagecoach and it looks like I will be using this in the future :) I am enthusiastic about Apostrophe and I have plans deploy it in several projects. My main struggle is with documentation.  I've gone through the tutorials and how-tos and have many questions. Is there any other documentation available? I'd be willing to write some docs as I go if needed.

Comment: Documentation is here, http://apostrophecms.org/docs/ 
More in-depth module reference is here http://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/index.html

Some documentation we're currently looking for is here https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Adocumentation

Answer (score 0):

My bad :(   Apostrophe had been upgraded from 2.39.1 to 2.45.0. Reverting back to the previous version solved all issues. I've adjusted my package.json accordingly:

```
"dependencies": {
    "apostrophe": "2.39.1",
     ...
```

I'll upgrade when I'm ready and have the time.

My simple migration process as specified above works OK.